# How to convert below xpath to css?

Tags: xpath, css-selectors

How to change this XPath to CSS selector?

```
//div[following-sibling::div[contains(@class, 'active-member')]]
```

Does any XPath can be converted to CSS selector?

Answer (score 0):

Not every XPath can be converted to CSS selector.
CSS selectors [do not support matching elements according to their texts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text) and [not supporting traversing up to parent elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)
As about converting this specific XPath to CSS selector I think it will be

```
div+div.active-member
```

However I'm not fully sure about this